# In English language acquisition, is it really important to stick to any standard accent?

Tags: british-english, accent

English, as a global language, has unavoidably a lot of varieties. When we learn English do we really have to stick to one specific variety ? If yes why and which?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](http://ell.stackexchange.com)? I think your question might be more suited to that site.

Comment: US Midwestern, obviously.

Comment: Queen's English, if you please. :)

Comment: More seriously, the important thing is to speak in such a way that your listener understands what you say, which in the global village is harder than it sounds.

Answer (score 2):

Great question. Yes, English has many varieties, but as far as I know only two of them are normally taught in a classroom context: **British English** (assuming [Received Pronunciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation)) and **American English** (assuming [General American](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/General_American)).

To make a decision, ask yourself:

> 1. **Which version will be more useful to me?** (Professionally, travel-wise, etc.)
> 2. **Which version am I likely to more easily imitate?** (Maybe you have a knack for RP, but not GenAm.)
> 3. **Which version will I hear more often?**
> 4. **Which version sounds more appealing to me?** (Some learners feel that RP sounds more "prestigious" or "proper", etc.)

Note that whichever version you choose, **you will be understood by most English speakers around the world, despite the pronunciation and speech pattern differences**.

However, let me offer several **pragmatic advantages of going with GenAm**:

1. **GenAm dominates the media.** You'll have no shortage of movies, shows, etc., and those are important (and entertaining) learning aids.
2. **GenAm dominates the internet.** Think YouTube, podcasts, lectures, etc.
3. This is a bit of a guesstimate, but **there are many orders of magnitude more speakers of General American than those of RP.** According to Wikipedia, RP is [spoken by roughly 3% of the British population](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation). By contrast, General American (or its close approximation) is very common in the US.

So for example, if your job puts you in a position to communicate with a British person, chances are, this won't help your RP very much. But if the guy or gal is American, they'll probably be speaking GenAm.

To answer your other question: No, you don't *have to* stick with a specific variety. It's up to you. Many people seem to mix and match and feel just fine :) Just make sure you can *understand* both General American and RP and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Good answer, @A.P.  And if Lexis English is still flipping a coin between RP and GenAm, you might bear in mind that all British people are very familiar with GenAm  -  we hear so much on TV, radio and in movies  -  that GenAm might really be the modern lingua franca.

Answer (score 0):

The **Transatlantic** version was popular some decades ago: a rhotic mix of American and British pronunciation without any regional nonsense and with emphasized clarity.

Today, the **American Theater Standard** is most likely what one should aim for. It is rhotic. It is free of drawn-out vowels. It is very light on nasal sounds. No affectation. No Eastern Seaboard, Brooklyn-inspired sing-song tones. No mouth-filled-with-marbles that today passes for genuine British talk. No Cockney sound-chewing, no Irish brogue or west country lilt. In other words, it is clean, sensible, and, when used correctly, quite beautiful.